# php (form insertcell) add mysql column

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

How the mysql add column insert? Because `insertCell` form I dont Know. I can try but I cant..add mysql column.This is my code javascript form with php. Actually I know Php pdo but this hard, I think.

How the mysql add column insert?

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table1");
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell1.innerHTML = "<input name='agirlik' type='text' required='required'  placeholder='0'  style='width:90%; margin-top:15px;' onkeypress='return fun_AllowOnlyAmountAndDot(this.id);' onchange='this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '.')' autofocus>";
  cell2.innerHTML = "<input name='en' type='text'   style='width:90%;margin-top:15px;' placeholder='0' onkeypress='return fun_AllowOnlyAmountAndDot(this.id);' onchange='this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '.')'>";
  cell3.innerHTML = "<input name='boy' type='text' style='width:90%;margin-top:15px;' placeholder='0' onkeypress='return fun_AllowOnlyAmountAndDot(this.id);' onchange='this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '.')'>";
  cell4.innerHTML = "<input name='yuks' type='text' style='width:90%;margin-top:15px;'  placeholder='0' onkeypress='return fun_AllowOnlyAmountAndDot(this.id);' onchange='this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '.')'>";
}

function myDeleteFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("table1").deleteRow(-1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>`enter code here`

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="add.php">
    <table width="550px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table1">
      <tr>
        <br>
        <td colspan="4"><a onclick="myFunction1()" style="color: #fff; margin-top: 10px"><i></i> Paket Ekle</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a onclick="myDeleteFunction1()" style="color: #000; margin-top: 10px"><i ></i> Paket Sil</a></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="40" valign="bottom"><strong>Paket Ağırlık (Kg.)</strong></td>
        <td valign="bottom"><strong>Eni  (cm.)</strong></td>
        <td valign="bottom"><strong>Boyu  (cm.)</strong></td>
        <td valign="bottom"><strong>Yüksekliği  (cm.)</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="agirlik" type="text" required="" id="agirlik" placeholder="0" style="width:90%; margin-top: 15px"></td>
        <td><input name="en" type="text" id="en" placeholder="0" required="" style="width:90%; margin-top: 15px"></td>
        <td><input name="boy" type="text" id="boy" placeholder="0" required="" style="width:90%; margin-top: 15px"></td>
        <td><input name="yuks" type="text" id="yuks" placeholder="0" required="" style="width:90%; margin-top: 15px"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="gonder">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If this is related to PHP and you have a problem with it you should add it to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking, trying to do or where you're stuck. Please edit the question and try and add more details. Also what does the posted code have to do with MySQL or PHP?

Comment: Sorry I can write missing , This true : <form action="add.php" method="post">

And my table name  = pack;
My Table Column = id,agirlik,en,boy,yuks;

one question = How should my "add.php" page be?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Right now, your question is likely to be closed soon because it's broad and it lacks specifics. You've tagged a number of technologies that don't seem to relate to any code you've posted, and it seems like you're asking us to write your entire function to insert data to the database. You're much more likely to get helpful responses if you can reduce your problem to a few steps, maybe a few lines of code setting up your database connection and then "When I call `mysqli_query()`, I always get a 'database not selected' error" or something specific like that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can write missing , This true : form action="add.php" method="post"

And my table name  = pack;
My Table Column = id,agirlik,en,boy,yuks;

one question = How should my "add.php" page be?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should edit your original question (there should be an "Edit" link above) rather than posting additional comments as an "Answer." On this site, it's hard to see that answers relate to the question and as more answers or comments appear, yours will probably drift further down (or be removed outright), which makes it hard for people to know you've added more.